# Height of a k ary tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree

I am trying to implement a function that calculates the height of a k-ary tree. My tree structure is like this:

```
struct node {
    int kids_num;
    int data;
    struct node **kids;
};
```

Function:

```
int height(struct node *root)
{
     if (root == NULL)
         return -1;

     for (int i = 0; i < root->kids_num; i++)
     {
          height(...)
     }

     return ??
}
```

Can you help me with the rest of the body of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of a tree, is the maximum of the height of its subtrees + 1.
The height of a tree without subtrees is 1.

The function height should then get the height of each of its subtress and keep the biggest of these values. It the returns this biggest value + 1.

```
int height(struct node *root)
{
     if (root == NULL)
         return -1;

     int maxHeight = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < root->kids_num; i++)
     {
          int h = height(root->kids[i]);
          if (h > maxHeight)
              maxHeight = h;
     }
     return maxHeight + 1;
}
```